# Program works with for loops but not with while loops?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, while-loop

**EDIT:** I have edited in the output of the program.

The program calls for estimating a given value mu. User gives a value of mu, and also provides four different numbers not equal to 1 (call them w, x, y, z). The program then attempts to find an estimate of the mu value by using the de Jaeger formula.

If I enter values of 238,900 for mu, and w=14, x=102329, y=1936, z=13
then the value of estimate should be 239,103, and the error about .08%.

My code with the for loops works perfectly fine:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleReader in = new SimpleReader1L();
    SimpleWriter out = new SimpleWriter1L();

    double bestEstimate = 0; // used to hold the estimate the computer while return

    double bestA = 0, bestB = 0, bestC = 0, bestD = 0; // to hold the values of the exponents for each number

    double[] exponents = { -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, -1.0 / 2.0, -1.0 / 3.0,
            -1.0 / 4.0, 0, 1.0 / 4.0, 1.0 / 3.0, 1.0 / 2.0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    double[] userNumbers = new double[4];

    double mu = getPositiveDouble(in, out);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        userNumbers[i] = getPositiveDoubleNotOne(in, out);
    }

    for (int a = 0; a < exponents.length; a++) {
        double a1 = Math.pow(userNumbers[0], exponents[a]);
        for (int b = 0; b < exponents.length; b++) {
            double b1 = Math.pow(userNumbers[1], exponents[b]);
            for (int c = 0; c < exponents.length; c++) {
                double c1 = Math.pow(userNumbers[2], exponents[c]);
                for (int d = 0; d < exponents.length; d++) {
                    double d1 = Math.pow(userNumbers[3], exponents[d]);

                    double currentEstimate = a1 * b1 * c1 * d1;
                    if (Math.abs(mu - currentEstimate) < Math
                            .abs(mu - bestEstimate)) {
                        bestEstimate = currentEstimate;
                        bestA = exponents[a];
                        bestB = exponents[b];
                        bestC = exponents[c];
                        bestD = exponents[d];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    out.println("Best estimate: " + bestEstimate);
    out.println(userNumbers[0] + "^" + bestA + ", " + userNumbers[1] + "^"
            + bestB + ", " + userNumbers[2] + "^" + bestC + ", "
            + userNumbers[3] + "^" + bestD);
    out.println("Error: " + calculateError(mu, bestEstimate) * 100 + "%");

}
```

Output:

```
 Enter a positive real number: 238900
 Enter a positive real number that isn't 1: 14
 Enter a positive real number that isn't 1: 102329
 Enter a positive real number that isn't 1: 1936
 Enter a positive real number that isn't 1: 13
 Best estimate: 239102.78648033558
 14.0^-5.0, 102329.0^1.0, 1936.0^0.5, 13.0^4.0
 Error: 0.08488341579555334%
```

However, with the while loops, I am unable to replicate this.

```
while (a < exponents.length) {
        double a1 = Math.pow(userNumbers[0], exponents[a]);
        while (b < exponents.length) {
            double b1 = Math.pow(userNumbers[1], exponents[b]);
            while (c < exponents.length) {
                double c1 = Math.pow(userNumbers[2], exponents[c]);
                while (d < exponents.length) {
                    double d1 = Math.pow(userNumbers[3], exponents[d]);
                    double currentEstimate = a1 * b1 * c1 * d1;
                    if (Math.abs(mu - currentEstimate) < Math
                            .abs(mu - bestEstimate)) {
                        bestEstimate = currentEstimate;
                        bestA = exponents[a];
                        bestB = exponents[b];
                        bestC = exponents[c];
                        bestD = exponents[d];

                    }
                    d++;

                }
                c++;

            }
            b++;

        }
        a++;

    }
```

Output:

```
Enter a positive real number: 238900
Enter a positive real number that isn't 1: 14
Enter a positive real number that isn't 1: 102329
Enter a positive real number that isn't 1: 1936
Enter a positive real number that isn't 1: 13
Best estimate: 0.0
14.0^0.0, 102329.0^0.0, 1936.0^0.0, 13.0^0.0
```

Comment: In your for loops you are initializing the counting variable every time in the while loops you are not initializing the variables a, b , c, d every time.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't initialized the variables for the next few iterations.

You need to reinitialize the variables used for while loop's condition check outside their respective while loops. i.e

```
b = 0;
while(b < exponents.length){
}
```

Similarly do it for the while loops which use variables `c` & `d`.

Answer (score 0):

[Daniel's answer is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48593245/3992939) : the 
structure of the `while` loop should be:

```
    int a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0;
    while (a < length) {

        b=0;
        while (b < length) {
            c=0;
            while (c < length) {
                d=0;
                while (d < length) {
                    d++;
                }
                c++;
            }
            b++;
        }
        a++;
    }
```